# Office 2013 Products suddenly can't be started

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2013

On a customer PC since this morning no Microsoft Office 2013 products are starting. (Excel, Word, Outlook).

- no error message is displayed
- no entries in event log (app and system during the try to start the application)
- procmon doesn't show any abnormal missing executable's

Office 2013 is home and business, Operating System is Windows 7.

The last action we seen in programs and files is "samsung printers live update" running.

Comment: The first thing I would do is reinstall the product this should obviously be done after a simply restart.

Comment: Also try starting in safe mode (e.g., "outlook.exe /safe")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing usual actions helped (reinstall office and so on). So we started the uninstall of Office 2013 to make a new installation. After running the unistall we saw that the programs were still on the pc. Starting the programs they are working again.

I know, this sounds like deinstalling only a hotfix and not the whole suite. But the entry we clicked was the whole Office 2013.